# Cell Value text does not appear

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am using a VS 2012 Windows Forms datagridview control. The datasource for the grid is a JObject but I have one predefined column that is supposed to display data from one of the datasource cells, which is also a JObject. After the datasource is assigned to the grid, I loop through the rows and add the new values. But it doesn't work quite right.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
{
    JObject account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(dgv.Rows[i].Cells["incomeAccount"].Value.ToString());
    dgv.Rows[i].Cells["account"].Value = account["accountName"];
}
```

This console output actually shows the correct text, for instance, "John Smith". Howver when the grid is finished loading, the cells in that colunm are all blank. The datagridview column is not read only. Is there something else I need to do to get the new data to appear?

Comment: what is the value of `account["accountName"]` when you are in the debugger.. ? also how are you binding the dgv? I don't see a DataSource

Comment: account["accountName"] is something like "John Smith". Just a simple string. I actually have 8 datagrids that follow a similar pattern. The datasource is the return value of an API call, thus the JSON. `public List<JObject>[] importData = new List<JObject>[8];` The grid creates columns and displays all of the records from the API. `dgv.DataSource = this.importData[i];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid has to be the active control to update cell values after databinding. Calling dgv.focus() before the for loop fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

DataGridView likes data binding. Create an array of objects that have the properties you want to see, and then set that array to your DataGridView.DataSource property.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am using data binding, but in one case where the cell value ends up being JObject, I need to take one field from that JObject and display it in another cell. So I am setting the datasource and trying to edit one cell (the whole column actually)

Comment: I can't modify the cell with the JObject because I have to import that data. In the VS designer, I have manually added the new (not from datasource) column.

Comment: Create a new class that has all the data you want displayed, including that new column. Fill up an array of that class with the data you were already binding to the dgv, and fill that additional property with your Json source. Then data bind on that new array. Does that make sense? Basically, prepare all your data before you bind it, not in multiple steps.

Comment: I really did not want to do that. I was trying to keep everything in JSON as much as possible without making some huge POCO to hold all the API data. I solved the problem a different way. Ty.